# Encoded URI doesn't work like the src attribute for iframe in IE11

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

I try to generate **src** attribute for the **iframe** on the fly doing this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

var html = '<html> <head></head> <body></body> </html>';
var eventListener = '<script>window.addEventListener("message", someListenerFunction)</script>';

iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html) + encodeURI(eventListener);
iframe.sandbox = 'allow-scripts';
```

This actually works fine in chrome/firefox/safari, but it **doesn't work** with ie11. Inside the iframe window it returns:

> Cannot display the webpage

And in the console I get the error:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
>   File: unknowprotocol.htm, Line:1, Column:1

The problem I think in the **encoded URI** address.

The reason I do this - I need to generate lots of iframes and I don't want to create a static webpages for each of them.

Hope for your help. Thank you in advance.